# Sidebar breaking and going to the footer

Tags: html, css

It is my first time trying to convert a template and the sidebar keeps going under the footer in lowest monitor's resolution, it isn't fixed at right side.

Index.html -

```
<section id="content_wrapper">
<header id="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-left">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span> <li class="crumb-trail">Watching</li> - <?php echo ucfirst($subtopic); ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <?php if ($subtopic == '' || $subtopic == 'home') { ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?PHP echo $main_content; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Server Info -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel" id="p15">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title text-info fw700"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Server Status</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body pn">
                -- code 2
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" id="p16">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title text-info fw700"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Legend Castle</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body pn">
                -- code 3
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" id="p17">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title text-info fw700"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Information</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body pn">
                -- code 4
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" id="p18">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title text-info fw700"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> Top 5 Level</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body pn">
                -- code 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Theme.css - The file is too big so I decided to host it: http://pastetool.com/pastebin/886681

You can see it live in http://test.auraot.com

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar `#sidebar_left` has margin top that is pushing it down and that is why you have unexpected results. I see you use the margin to push the sidebar away from your header but there is a way to achieve that without pushing the element like: (actually there are two ways to fix it)

WAY no.1 padding / box-sizing combo

```
// well remove the margin-top
margin-top: 0;
// add it as padding-top instead
padding: 60px 0 40px;
// make the elements size compensate with the padding value this
// means that this padding will not create extra space outside
// element
box-sizing: border-box;
```

WAY no.2 make use of it being positioned absolute

```
// still remove the margin-top
margin-top: 0;
// put it on top instead
top: 60px;
// do not give it a height
height: auto;
// also do not give it a min-height
min-height: 0;
// add bottom 0;
bottom: 0;
```

what happened here is that `position: absolute` elements has this hidden feature where you can make it behave like `height: 100%` BUT using `top and bottom` same thing work with `left and right` where if you put `top: 60px and bottom: 0` it will automatically fill its height based from the distance of your `top and bottom` values though this highly depends on its parents height.

there you have the same look without pushing the element away.
hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a glove! Also, I'm facing two others problems that I really don't know how I should fix them. The first is the login part, seems it been broken at phones, and the second one it to move the right side bar on phones, it isn't working as well too.

Comment: If that helped you with your problem don't forget to marked it as a answer. If your new problems aren't related to this question then make a question about that certain problem you have encountered

Comment: Oh, thanks! But I got another bug in the sidebar left, that with the example that you provided showed up! The bar is bugged, http://prntscr.com/gf7y1s

Comment: I believe you missed something, as I have checked it `padding solution` did not make in your code,  as you removed the margin you should move the margin-top value to `padding-top` then add `box-sizing: border-box` as stated. OR simply add `top: 60px` that would work

Comment: It stil isn't working and I'm using like `#sidebar_left {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 230px;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #30363e;
}`

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit my last comment, but, if I use top: 60px starts a flaw in the right side bar that miss a part http://prntscr.com/gf86is

Comment: actually if you want to implement the `absolute` solution you need to remove the `height` means you need to remove `min-height` too then put `bottom: 0`.

Comment: remove remove `min-height`? because if you add `top: 60px` and the sidebar has a height of 100% means it just behaves as before the margin problem. To eliminate it you need to remove the static height both `height` and `min-height` and let `top:0, bottom: 0` the the job.

Comment: Already did that and the issue continues ```#sidebar_left {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 230px;
  padding-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px 0 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #30363e;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `padding-top:100px` above `<section id="content_wrapper">`
So the the result will be looks like this

```
    <style type="text/css">
          div.pad-top{padding-bottom:100px}
    <style>

    <div class="pad-top"></div>
    <section id="content_wrapper">
```

Just measure the amount of `padding-top` that you need by change the `100px`

Comment: Hello, I made what you said, and still not working, in small monitors the sidebar still on the footer.

Comment: but on your website the top menu and side bar are works perfectly, what could go wrong on this website ? can you be more specific ? or you already got the answer ? first time i seen the the top menu and side bar looks weird but now it's look good, can you give me screenshot whic <div> that you said small monitor ? please update your question